# Prevent pagebreak between section header and figure

Tags: floats, sectioning, page-breaking

In a document, I have an appendix with several screenshots, i.e., the different figures are displayed without any descriptive text right after the section header.

I notice, however, that in several cases, the figure environment and the header section are separated on different pages. I would like to avoid this, i.e., ideally, the header should then be moved to the next page.

Is there a **generic** solution for this? Ideally, I would have to renew the command for the section header, so that figures (or other blocks) and headers are not separated. I am stuck at this point though

Mini working example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[centerlast]{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{tikz}

\title{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Section 1}
%
\begin{figure}[tbh]
        \fbox{
            \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        }
        \fbox{
            \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        }
    \caption{Front and Back Side of the Device}
\end{figure}
%
\FloatBarrier
%
\section{Section 2}
%
\begin{figure}[tbh]
        \fbox{
            \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        }
        \fbox{
            \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        }
        \fbox{
            \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        }
    \caption{Main Interface of the Device}
\end{figure}
%
\FloatBarrier

\end{document}
```

Any suggestions or help with this matter are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I bet the figre box is just too big. Make the pics smaller.

Comment: the only reason to put the `\includegraphics` inside a `figure` environment is to allow latex to move it, if you want it definitely to come after the heading, don't do that, just use `\includegraphics` directly.

Comment: you can use `\includegraphics[..]{example-image}` in your MWE that is already included in most distributions for exactly this purpose, to save people downloading images.

Comment: David, yes, I realized this as well that the figure environment could be omitted. But what about the caption then? I would still like to include a caption.

Comment: Johannes_B, we are not talking of pictures with a specific size. I potentially do not know the true dimensions of the pictures that will get inserted. I use a script to generate most parts of the text body automatically, including the appendix with various figures/pictures

Comment: There is simply no way that the three-graph second figure will fit on the first page if you insist on setting the widths of the graphs to `0.48\textwidth`. However, if you reduce the widths of the three graphs in the second figure to ca. `0.29\textwidth`, the second `figure` environment *will* fit on the first page. OTOH, if the graphs must have width `0.48\textwidth`, simply insert `\clearpage` before the second `\section` directive.

Comment: If you use the showframe package you will see that there isn't enough room (width) for the first figure either.

Answer (score 4):

For such an appendix you don't really want the figures to float at all so rather than specifying that they float and hoping they don't, use `[H]` to tell latex not to float them, then the usual rules about keeping section headings with teh first text in the section will kick in.

I also added some `%` to ends of lines to avoid the overfull box warnings in the original.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[centerlast]{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{tikz}

\title{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Section 1}
%
\begin{figure}[H]
        \fbox{%
            \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image-b}%
        }\hfill
        \fbox{%
            \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image-b}%
        }
    \caption{Front and Back Side of the Device}
\end{figure}
%
\FloatBarrier
%
\section{Section 2}
%
\begin{figure}[H]
        \fbox{%
            \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image-b}%
        }\hfill
        \fbox{%
            \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image-b}%
        }\hfill
        \fbox{%
            \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image-b}%
        }
    \caption{Main Interface of the Device}
\end{figure}
%
\FloatBarrier

\end{document}
```

Comment: I use `[H]` and I still have a section on the end of one page and the figure on the next page.

Comment: @MartinThoma tex must have been desperate then and had no legal page break I guess, just put `\clearpage `before the section heading (assuming the heading and the figure fit on one page)

Comment: The problem is that I'm automatically generating LaTeX. I think I rather put all sections which contain only one figure / table in `\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}  <my content> \end{minipage}`. This should prevent them from getting separated and they still can be on one page.